# failure of Docker installation after deleting it Win10 Pro

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have delete docker's `hyper-V's VM (MobyLinuxVM)` and re-install `Docker`.
Now docker can not re-install his hyper-V VM.
I have check register, folder etc to find some trace of old vm or switch `(DockerNAT)` to clean theme but nothing found.
I just want to make a fresh install, any idea?

Here is docker error:
[Docker error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvQAJ.png)

> Unable to create: L’exécution de la commande s’est arrêtée, car la
>   variable de préférence « ErrorActionPreference » ou le paramètre
>   courant a la valeur Stop : Hyper-V n'a trouvé aucun commutateur
>   virtuel portant le nom « DockerNAT ». à New-Switch,  :
>   ligne 117 à ,  : ligne 394    à
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters) dans
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:ligne
>   36    à Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean
>   showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) dans
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:ligne
>   67    à Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0() dans
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:ligne
>   51    à Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() dans
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:ligne
>   59

I have allready try the procedure of re-installing `Hyper-V restart /install /restart /install docker`

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you open HyperV manager and check if DockerNAT is present under virtual switches?

Comment: I have check I can't create a new switch and DockerNAT not present.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Hyper-V yet?

Comment: Yes allready with correct procedure

Comment: Restarted your computer? And if that doesn't fix it I'm out of clues and letting it to someone else to figure it out. An alternative might be to install [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/)